# How do components interact with each other?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a project using express and using a component approach.
I have the following files structure:

```
components
 user
   index.js
   userModel.js
   userRouter.js
 auth
   index.js
   authRouter.js
   authController.js
```

As far as I understand, my components should not be linked directly, that is, it would be wrong to connect a user component in the authController.js file in order to check for an existing user during authorization.

authController.js:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const VKontakteStrategy = require('passport-vkontakte').Strategy;
const config = require('config')

passport.use(new VKontakteStrategy({
    clientID:     config.get('auth.vk.clientID'),
    clientSecret: config.get('auth.vk.clientSecret'),
    callbackURL:  `${config.get('domain')}/api/web/auth/vkontakte/callback`
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
      console.log(profile)
    User.findOrCreate({ vkontakteId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

module.exports = passport
```

The question is how, in this case, to connect these 2 components?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect" these components?  You can access the methods of component A from component B by using the "require" statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a nice `MVC` layer. The "issue" with `MVC` is that it doesn't address logic and where to put it (that is a good thing. As this design pattern should be adjusted to your logic and not the other way around).

I suggest adding a `business logic` layer (next to the components directory).

```
business_logic 
 user
  userService.js    // <--- Expose a well defined API for user
  userRepository.js // <--- DB stuff
components
 user
   index.js
   userModel.js
   userRouter.js
 auth
   index.js
   authRouter.js
   authController.js
```

Now if `userService.js` exposes the following methods:

```
 - create(user)
 - delete(userId)
 - update(userId, user)
 - getById(userId)
 - getAll(query)
 - getByAuth(username, password)
```

You can use the `getByAuth(username, password)` for `authController.js` and with the rest of the methods you can implement a CRUD API in a `userController.js`.